# MYSQL cursor repeats wrong data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm trying to create a stored procedure and a cursor for the first time, and it isn't behaving quite as expected.  Everything executes just fine, but the output data isn't correct.  If I manually iterate through, I get what I expect, but not via the stored procedure.

If you take a look at the output table below, the first three records are correct, and the GID is correct for all subsequent entries, however the PTS summary is not correct and repeats the same value.

Procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE creategamesummary()

BEGIN

DECLARE curdone TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE curgid INT;
DECLARE curwk INT;

DECLARE gamescursor CURSOR

FOR

SELECT g1.GID FROM games g1 WHERE g1.SEAS = 2008 AND g1.WK > 4 AND (g1.V = 'BAL' OR g1.H = 'BAL') ORDER BY GID;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET curdone=1;

OPEN gamescursor;

REPEAT
    FETCH gamescursor into curgid;

    SET curwk = (SELECT WK FROM games WHERE GID = curgid);

    REPLACE INTO gamesummary
    SELECT
    curgid as GID,
    SUM(t1.PTS) as PTS
FROM
    team t1
WHERE
    t1.GID IN (
    SELECT
    g2.GID
FROM
    games g2
WHERE
    (g2.V = 'BAL' OR
    g2.H = 'BAL') AND
    g2.SEAS = 2008 AND
    g2.WK <= curwk
) AND t1.TNAME = 'BAL';

UNTIL curdone END REPEAT;

    CLOSE gamescursor;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Output Table:

```
GID,PTS
2182,75
2196,78
2212,105
2223,127
2240,127
2259,127
2268,127
2288,127
2306,127
2327,127
2330,127
2346,127
2371,127
2379,127
2381,127
2385,127
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but I managed to refactor the query to the code below.  Since this is my first venture into cursors and stored procedures, I'd still appreciate feedback on what went wrong in the first version.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE creategamesummary2()

BEGIN

DECLARE curdone TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE curteam varchar(3);

DECLARE teamcursor CURSOR

FOR

SELECT TNAME FROM team WHERE GID in (SELECT GID from games WHERE SEAS = 2008) GROUP BY TNAME;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET curdone=1;

OPEN teamcursor;

WHILE NOT curdone DO
    FETCH teamcursor into curteam;

    REPLACE INTO gamesummary2
SELECT
    g1.GID,
    g1.WK,
    curteam AS TNAME,
    (
    SELECT SUM(t1.PTS)
    FROM team t1
    WHERE t1.GID IN (
        SELECT g2.GID
        FROM games g2
        WHERE g2.WK <= g1.WK AND (g2.V = curteam OR g2.H = curteam) AND g2.SEAS = 2008) AND
    t1.TNAME = curteam) AS SUM_PTS
FROM
    games g1
WHERE
    g1.SEAS = 2008 AND
    g1.WK > 4 AND
    (g1.V = curteam OR g1.H = curteam)
GROUP BY GID, WK, curteam;

END WHILE;

    CLOSE teamcursor;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```